# Why some tables contains only part of chains in iptables?

Tags: iptables, table

I am reading some tutorial on the webpage [iptables tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/).
There are five chains in iptables.

```
PREROUTING chain
OUTPUT chain
FORWARD chain
INPUT chain
POSTROUTING chain
```

And there are four tables in iptables.

```
filter table
nat  table
mangle table
raw table
```

Only mangle table contains all five types of chains.

Mangle table has the following built-in chains.

```
PREROUTING chain
OUTPUT chain
FORWARD chain
INPUT chain
POSTROUTING chain
```

1.Why filter table has the three following built-in chains ?

```
INPUT chain 
OUTPUT chain 
FORWARD chain
```

Why not contains five types of chains?

2.Why nat table has the three following built-in chains.

```
PREROUTING chain 
POSTROUTING chain 
OUTPUT chain
```

Why not contains five types of chains?

3.Why raw table  has the following two built-in chains?

```
PREROUTING chain
OUTPUT chain
```

Why not contains five types of chains?

Answer (score 2):

First try to understand what netfilter does, and what is the path of a packet in kernel space. (http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.svg)
[image]
And read docs from the original http://netfilter.org/ ; your linked iptables howto is very low quality.